# tunnel ssh client via socks5 proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy

putty has a Socks 5 support - so putty can connect through the Socks proxy to its target.

Now I would need to connect from a linuxshell with ssh via a socks proxy to any ssh-server. But ssh has no proxy support like putty.

Is there any solution which works under OpenWrt to tunnel ssh through my Socks 5 proxy?

Best Regards